# Cycles image sequence node offset and the object info random

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor

I have 3500 cubes and I want to randomly place about 119 different images on the sides of the cubes. I loaded the images into an image sequence node and changing the offset changes the picture. How can I connect the object info random node to the offset so that each cube gets a random texture?

I have tried using a driver to pass the value from a math node field, but it does not update with the object info random data...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

here is a quick and dirty script, its really inefficient though, creates a distinct material for each cube. I Suggest maybe investigating the animation nodes plugin? you can do fancier programming logic with that.

```
import bpy
import random
import glob

scene = bpy.context.scene


image_names = glob.glob("/Users/myuser/Blender/images/*")

for name in image_names:
    bpy.ops.image.open(filepath=name)

cube_count = 1000

for c in range(cube_count):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(view_align=False,
     enter_editmode=False,
      location=(3*random.random(), 3*random.random(), 3*random.random()))




for ind,ob in enumerate(scene.objects):
    if ob.type == 'MESH' and ob.name.startswith("Cube"):
        ob.select = True


        #make a new material
        rand = "--"+ str(random.randint(0,100))
        mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="Mat"+str(ind)) #set new material to variable
        #add the material to the object
        ob.data.materials.append(mat) 
        ob.active_material_index = len(ob.material_slots) - 1

        #make a new node texture node
        mat.use_nodes = True
        node_tree = mat.node_tree
        node = node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeTexImage")
        tex_coord_node = node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeTexCoord")
        mapping_node = node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeMapping")
        diff_node = node_tree.nodes['Diffuse BSDF']

        node_tree.links.new(tex_coord_node.outputs['Generated'],       mapping_node.inputs['Vector'])
        node_tree.links.new(mapping_node.outputs['Vector'], node.inputs['Vector'])
        node_tree.links.new(node.outputs['Color'], diff_node.inputs['Color'])

        node.projection = 'BOX'
        node.select = True
        node_tree.nodes.active = node


        rand_image_index = random.randint(0, len(bpy.data.images))
        node.image = bpy.data.images[rand_image_index]

    else: 
        ob.select = False
`
```

Comment: That is very cool thanks!
I was able to use animation nodes to change the value of the math node that is driving  the offset value in the image sequence node, however this only gives me the same random texture on each cube.

Comment: @Talmore try using a 'Object Info' node and hook up the random output into a math node 'add' then each object should have a random value in the image sequence.

Comment: I have the object info node. The problem is the offset value on the image sequence does not have an input. I set a driver to read from a math node that is attached to the object info, but the driver does not read the current data.

Comment: Ah, okay, heres another solution, stitch all 119 images together in 1 long jpg/png, then use the mapping node to change the x/y location based on the object info #. That way you don't depend on image seq #, but just on a X/Y displacement on a huge image map

Comment: saw the pile images into one file in my research. too hands on for the number of images down the road. I am currently working with animation nodes. I loaded the images onto planes. Then I create instances of them. The instance is placed on the face of the cubes. It is working so far. I need to rotate all of the images to keep the top edge the z-up